# R dplyr apply a function based on a condition after group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
data = data.frame(
    date = as.Date(c("2021-01-12","2021-01-13","2021-01-14",
    "2021-01-15","2021-01-12","2021-01-13","2021-01-14",
    "2021-01-12","2021-01-13", "2021-01-14")),
    id = c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b"),
    attrib = c("X","X","X","X","Y","Y","Y","X","X","X"),
    value = c(999999,1000,1001,988888,.1,.2,1000,1001,1002,999999))
>data
         date id attrib    value
1  2021-01-12  a      X 999999.0
2  2021-01-13  a      X   1000.0
3  2021-01-14  a      X   1001.0
4  2021-01-15  a      X 988888.0
5  2021-01-12  a      Y      0.1
6  2021-01-13  a      Y      0.2
7  2021-01-14  a      Y   1000.0
8  2021-01-12  b      X   1001.0
9  2021-01-13  b      X   1002.0
10 2021-01-14  b      X 999999.0
```

And I am trying to obtain the following output

```
         date id attrib    value
1  2021-01-13  a      X   1000.0
2  2021-01-14  a      X   1001.0
3  2021-01-12  a      Y      0.1
4  2021-01-13  a      Y      0.2
5  2021-01-14  a      Y   1000.0
6  2021-01-12  b      X   1001.0
```

My strategy is to use `group_by(id, attrib)` and `slice_max` the top 2 highest values given the condition that `attrib==X` (notice that row 9 with value 1002.0 will have to disappear).
The closest approach that I have found is this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66210729/dplyr-group-by-and-slice-within-group?rq=1) so, I am trying to make a script that look like the following in R:

```
data %>% group_by(id, attrib) %>%
    slice_max(
        if(attrib == "X") order_by = value, n = 2, with_ties = FALSE )
```

But I cannot get it done.
What I am missing or is there maybe a better way? My original dataframe has much more columns and much more categories within the columns. And only is some of the I would lie to apply the function to trim what is was more than an outlier in the data. Thank you.

Comment: You want to drop the two highest values in each group of `id` and `attrib`?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for:

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  filter(attrib == "X") %>%
  group_by(id, attrib) %>%
  slice_max(order_by=value, n=2) %>%
  anti_join(data, ., by=c("date", "id", "attrib"))
```

returns

```r
        date id attrib  value
1 2021-01-13  a      X 1000.0
2 2021-01-14  a      X 1001.0
3 2021-01-12  a      Y    0.1
4 2021-01-13  a      Y    0.2
5 2021-01-14  a      Y 1000.0
6 2021-01-12  b      X 1001.0
```

Comment: Thank you @Martin Gal, bghn

Comment: @eliasmaxil Feel free to accept an answer (not necesserily mine) if it helped you solving your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is after grouping by 'id', `filter` the 'value' not (`!`) `%in%` the `sort`ed `head` of 'value' where 'attrib' is 'X'

```
library(dplyr)
 data %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    filter(!value %in% head(sort(value[attrib == 'X'], 
         decreasing = TRUE), 2)) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  date       id    attrib  value
  <date>     <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
1 2021-01-13 a     X      1000  
2 2021-01-14 a     X      1001  
3 2021-01-12 a     Y         0.1
4 2021-01-13 a     Y         0.2
5 2021-01-14 a     Y      1000  
6 2021-01-12 b     X      1001
```